# Chef Inspec test code for checking presence of installed software in control panel

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I need to write chef inspec test code for verifying a software is present or not in control panel(programme and feature) for windows.I have one idea that I can use powershel script inside chef inspec.But I need a powershell script which list out all the software from control panel(programme and feature) option.I am using below powershell script but is not working fine.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/*  |
Select-Object Displayname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

describe package('package_name') do
 it { should be_installed }
end

Comment: Or in powershell win32_Product class will return installed products, so gwmi win32_Product | where { $_.Name -eq 'name' } etc.

Comment: Thanks I have used later one. Working fine.